# Ubuntu 19.04 - Lock screen shortcut doesn't work

Tags: lock-screen, 19.04

After upgrade to 19.04 keyboard shortcut (Super + L) doesn't work anymore - means nothing happens. I've tried to change the shortcut to different combination and it's the same. Other shortcuts (e.g. Super + A) work well.

I can lock session via menu item (lock icon) but it's a bit annoying.

I am using Gnome on Wayland.

Any tips where to look? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any answer to this.  I've got exactly the same issue

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using lightdm and screen lock is disabled in it due security issues. [Read more here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1806961)

You can check you display manager with: `sudo systemctl status display-manager`

If you still want to lock your screen with lightdm - you can use `dm-tool lock`. Also you can add it to keyboard shortcut as command (e.g. `Super+L`).

Switching to gdm3 helped: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`

Answer (score 0):

You should try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

It works for me!

Comment: It doesn't work. Have you tried on Ubuntu Wayland?