# Can't lock screen with shortcut on Ubuntu 20.04 gnome

Tags: gnome, lightdm, lock-screen, gdm, gnome-screensaver

In shortcuts i have <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> for locking screen. But on pressing it - nothing happens. In syslog:

```
gsd-media-keys[1979]: Couldn't lock screen: Cannot invoke method; 
proxy is for the well-known name org.gnome.ScreenSaver without an owner, and proxy was constructed with the G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_DO_NOT_AUTO_START flag
```

Locking from interface works fine.

System info: Ubuntu 19.04 upgraded to 20.04

`Linux laptop 5.4.0-21-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Sat Mar 28 13:10:28 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

`GNOME Shell 3.36.1`

Other info:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled = true
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen = false
```

`gnome-screensaver 3.6.1`

I also tried: `gnome-screensaver-command -l` but nothing happens.

I already tried to reinstall gnome-shell and gnome-screensaver - it didn't help.

How to fix locking screen from hotkey?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242110/after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04-lockscreen-not-working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My original question was banned as bug, but it isn't a bug - it's a wrong configuration. 
People faced this problem a lot in the internet and SO:

- [Ubuntu 19.04 - Lock screen shortcut doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144000/ubuntu-19-04-lock-screen-shortcut-doesnt-work/1245062)
- [Automatic screen lock not working Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240575/automatic-screen-lock-not-working-ubuntu-20-04/1245067)

In my case I was using lightdm and screen lock is disabled in it due security issues. [Read more here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1806961)

You can check you display manager with: `sudo systemctl status display-manager`

If you still want to lock your screen with lightdm - you can use `dm-tool lock`. Also you can add it to keyboard shortcut as command (e.g. `Super+L`).

Switching to gdm3 helped: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`

Comment: how to use dm-tool lock with `super + L`? I have to insist with lightdm, but I also want to lock the screen with shotcuts. Thanks

Comment: @ToughMind add custom keyboard shortcut. Search "shortcuts" in your System Settings or find this section in Keyboard settings.

Answer (score 5):

I face same problem after I switched my display-manager to lightdm. (because I prefer the design of lightdm over gdm)

However, I still want to lock the screen with keyboard shortcut.

So this is what I did:
Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts > '+'
Name : lightdm_lockscreen
Command : `dm-tool lock`
Shortcut : <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (I edited original Lock Screen shortcut to other combination)

In my case, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> enables the lock of the screen perfectly with this setting.
Enjoy :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and none of the above worked. Had to use dconf-editor and navigate to /org/gnome/desktop/lockdown and unset 'disable-lock-screen'.

Hope this helps someone else.